# Filtering legend by Attribute in print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression, qgis-print-layouts

I have a map layer with two fields in the attribute table: "name" and "Type".

I want to print a map with all variations of "Type" marked on it, but filter the Legend by an specific value in the Type field.

Eg. Type can be: Trail, Path, Access Road etc and all of these need to be displayed on the map but in the legend I only want to display Trails.

I managed this a couple of weeks ago but can't remember what I did. I seem to remember something about unticking Auto Update in the Legend Items and then adding an expression but no matter what I now try. Nothing filters my legend.

QGIS v 3.24.3

[image: The Legend as it is with everything that is in the layer displayed]

[image: Example of the Layers Attribute Table with the Type Field of "Trail" being the only ones I want displayed in the legend.]

Comment: Why don't you check with the old project how it worked there?

Comment: A better question would be "Why didn't you think to save the project?" Yup. My own fault.

Comment: Can you provide example data and an image of how the legend should look like?

Comment: I've attached a couple of screenshots to my question.

Comment: But how should the legend look like?

Comment: For now, exactly the same but wihout any Access Trail, Access Path or Access Roads listed. later on I want to try some other things but this is all I need for now.

Answer (score 1):

In the Legend item's properties, turn off `Auto update`, select the layer whose legend you want to filter, then click the little expression filter button down the bottom right:

[image]

Then you can write a filtering expression, for my example I used `"type" = 'type_2'` which results in:

[image]

You would used the expression `"Type" = 'Trail'`

Comment: Hi TeddyTedTed, thanks for your reply. This still isn't filtering and all my tails and paths are visible both in the legend and in the Item properties pane. It's odd as I was sure I'd done exactly this previously and it worked.

Comment: @DigitalEssence that's odd. In that case go with J.R's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to duplicate your layer then to filter those layer to get one to display what you want to see in the legend and the other to display all the rest. After that it's just a mater of using the right layer to build your legend.

One bonus with this solution is it make easier to make more prominent the feature that appear in legend (like putting them on top, or using a slight transparency on the other feature)